# If-statement put in for instruction

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, time

Edited: n is a constant. It doesn't change inside the loop.

Given the 2 cases:

1)

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
             ...
else 
    for(i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
             ...
```

2)

```
for(i = 1; i <= 9 + (n % 2 == 0); i++)
          ...
```

Is there a difference in time between the 2 cases? (Case 2) Verifying every step if `n` is an even number (or just an additional condition) should run the program a bit slower, am I correct?

Comment: Compare the generated assembly code for both. And run each variant a million time while measuring. And remember to build with optimizations enabled before comparing or benchmarking.

Comment: If the optimizer can figure out that n definitely never changes and therefore `(9 + (n % 2 == 0))` is a constant for the loop, then it might be the same.  The only way to know is to check

Comment: If you want to know about performance you need to measure it.  On todays modern CPU with speculative execution, out-of-order execution, instruction/data pre-fetch etc even examining the generated code will not help you..

Comment: You will probably get the exact same assembly for both

Comment: if there was a difference here the difference would be so small that it would be extremely difficult to measure with any accuracy.

Comment: @drescherjm it depends on how `n` defined and what loop does

Comment: Specifically `n % 2` is the same as `n & 1`, which is half a clock cycle on a PC. Why bother?

Comment: I assumed `n` was a constant inside the loop. Otherwise the if() version would not work.

Comment: @drescherjm you can assume but compiler cannot

Comment: You are correct. Now I see what you are saying. If the compiler can not detect you will probably pay a few cycle penalty for the `9 + (n % 2 == 0)` calculation. If this loop was run inside of another loop that was executed millions of times the 1 to 3 clock cycles wasted * 9 or 10 could easily add up to a measurable difference.

Answer (score 4):

> Verifying every step if n is an even number (or just an additional condition) should run the program a bit slower, am I correct?

In general case yes, in this particular case it depends if you can change `n` inside loop and what is `n` ie can compiler detect that `n` could be changed or not to optimize it. So you should make your intention clear for readers and compiler:

```
auto limit = 9 + (n % 2 == 0); 
for(i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
      ...
```

Comment: maybe, you also want to substitute `auto limit = 9 + (n % 2 == 0);` with `auto limit = 10 - (n%2);`.
IMHO is even clearer without that `==0`

Comment: @Federico that's subjective, I just used style OP prefers and do not want to insist particular way when it does not change anything else.